# Why iPhone App not getting any Revunue from iAds after getting Requests and impressions also?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, app-store-connect, iad

In My iphone application i added iAd Control i am getting Requests and impressions but i am not getting revenue. Why it is happening? Do we have to do something to get Revenue?

I am very confused. Some one says about CPI(Cost Per Impression). But I am not getting how to enable CPI.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app revenues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much that advertiser is paying, they might pay 20 cents per thousand impressions, so if you have 10 impressions, you would have 0.  It all just varies, if you are seeng requests and impressions, you are fine, there's not much you can do other than get more people to use your app thus getting more impressions.

Comment: Right now i am getting 77 impressions and 573 requests it means i will be get revenue after 1000 impressions only?

Comment: Not exactly, it depends on how much is being payed by the advertiser. There are advertisers who pay a lot and advertisers who pay little.  Just all depends.